# Android - can't retrieve data from firebase with a given uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My `Firebase database` structure is:

[image]

I want to retrieve the full name of some user, when I have its key.

**My code:**

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button logbutton,wantToDeliverButton,lookForButton;
    private String userName;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Firebase usersRef = new Firebase("https://myfirstfirebaseauth.firebaseio.com");
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class));
        }
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        Firebase ref = usersRef.child("User").child(user.getUid());
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                userName = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getFullName();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        textView.setText("welcome "+userName);
    }
}
```

But it set the `textView` to `null`. I try to put Toast inside the `onDataChange()` method, but it doesn't work. It seems it doesn't even get inside the method.

The line `FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();` is correct because if i'm writing `textView.setText("welcome "+ user.getEmail());` - I really get the correct email.

How to solve this? Am I using the correct listener? I don't want to change anything in the database, just retrieve.

**Edit:** it goes to `onCancelled()`.

Comment: your question is NOT `android-studio` related. Do not spam with inproper tags! Tag removed.

Comment: Sorry mate, i wrote it in android studio..didn't mean to spam..

Comment: it does not matter what tools you use. You tag in relation to your problem -  so if it is `firebase` related code you got problems with, you tag it `firebase` only (`java` is also not realally related - you are not having any problems with java language here), What tool you use to create that code is no relevant for your question.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski you're right about the Android Studio tagging. But keep in mind that most devs don't mean harm when they tag, they just don't realize the tag doesn't help (and hurts people with actual Android Studio related problems). I just edit the tags and if they repeat it, a gentle reminder goes a long way. I nowadays often compare it to asking "How long should I marinate tri-tip steak?" and then tagging with [kitchen]. :-)

Comment: @user3552460 @qbix hits the nail on its head about mixing versions. Aside from that, it is likely that your user doesn't have read permission to the node and you're attaching the listener before they're authenticated. In your `onCancelled` always at least throw the error: `throw firebaseError.toException()`, otherwise you're hiding problems such as this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen its really about the permissions. I edited the rules in my Firebase to be {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null"
  }
} and now its working, but its not good approach i think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing capabilities from the legacy 2.5.X Firebase SDK (Example:  [Firebase.setAndroidContext()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_setAndroidContext)) and the new 9.X.X SDK (Example: [FirebaseAuth.getInstance()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getInstance())).  That is almost certainly a recipe for failure.  Rework your code to use only the new SDK.  The [Setup Guide is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup).

Comment: Thanks a lot - all i had to do is to change 'Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);' to 'FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();'