# failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied every time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the Firebase Auth service with email and password. I am trying to do :

1. Login User
2. after successfully login, I want to fetch data from Firebase Database.

Got Log `[onAuthStateChanged:signed_in: "xyz"]`. after that Log  Every time I got Permission denied and also getting this :

> [W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for
>        com.google.firebase.auth not found].

My Database Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "Person" :{
          ".read": "auth !== null",
          ".write": "auth !== null"
       }
  }
}
```

My Code

```
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(onClickBtnLogIn);

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://firebaseapplink/Person");
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Map<String, Object> userData = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        Log.d("TAG", "User Data :" + userData);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                        Log.d("TAG", firebaseError.getMessage()); // Permission Denied

                    }
                });

            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
        }
    };
}



      View.OnClickListener onClickBtnLogIn = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final String Email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String Password = edtPwd.getText().toString().trim();

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(abc.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                    {

                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Log.d("SignIn", "task");
                        }
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) 
                        {
                            Log.d("SignIn", "task fail");
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    auth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing database services from the legacy 2.x SDK with `FirebaseAuth` from the new 9.4.0 SDK.  They are not compatible. Remove `compile com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.x.x` from your build dependencies, replace with compile `com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0`, and make the [code change](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/)s needed to use [FirebaseDatabase](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase).

Comment: This has been answered before, likely by yourself. :-) Can you find a dupe and mark it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39319741/4815718

Comment: Thanks @qbix! Closed the question, upvoted your answer here too though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added dependency for that in your `build.gradle` file.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

Comment: already using 9.4.0 : compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0"  stll getting "Permission Denied".

Comment: try to use google-services.json , don't  directly use Firebase in your java files, and make sure you have added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in build.gradle file under root project.

Comment: try to downgrade dependency like this, compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'

Comment: Alreday i have added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0 and also tried with compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0' but not working.

Comment: Is it because you're already signed in and you're trying to sign in again?  Permission denied for what?  For auth or for database access? If you showed all your code, then that is what I suspect the reason might be -- you should only sign in if you're signed out otherwise you will have an existing session.  Did you write your own sign-In class?  They already have a nice example: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/EmailPasswordActivity.java

Comment: permission denied for fetching data from firebase database.