# Android Firebase Auth and setValue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to save data in my firebase database with authentication. I have this code and I'm authenticate:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.v(TAG+" hola", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivityGoogle.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                actualizardatos();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but when i try to save data with actualizardatos() they tell me  W/RepoOperation: setValue at /users/xxxxx failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied

actualizardatos():

```
public void actualizardatos(){
    String FIREBASE_URL = "https://admob-app-id-5989251146.firebaseio.com/";
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(SignInActivityGoogle.this);
    database=new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    String user=acct.getId();
    Firebase firebase;
    assert user != null;
    firebase = database.child("users").child(user);
    firebase.setValue(user);
}
```

my rules:

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
        ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      ".read": "auth !== null",
            ".write": "auth != null",
      "$user_id":{
        ".read": "auth !== null",
                ".write": "auth != null",
        "coins":{
          ".read": "auth !== null",
                    ".write": "auth != null"
        },
        "level":{
          ".read": "auth !== null",
                    ".write": "auth != null"
        },
        "listitems":{
          ".read": "auth !== null",
                    ".write": "auth != null"
        },
        "lastsave":{
          ".read": "auth !== null",
                    ".write": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Problem solved, I was mixing codes. My problem is that, within a guide, Google change languages​ and change names, that confuses me and I look for how to do things and I mix codes.

Example: In this guide, Google explain how to log in the database in starter guide and we can see the final variable DatabaseReference myRef, but in the save data, in Spanish, I have one variable named mDatabase without class, is the same variable but different names, I confuse and look for help with other code.

Comment: You cannot use `FirebaseAuth` from the new 9.X SDK and database services from the legacy 2.5.x SDK.  You need to use [FirebaseDatabase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) from the new SDK.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39319741/4815718

Comment: i read the guide and use the guide code :S is so confuse the api, i read two diferents firebase versions trying to integrate

Comment: `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` is from the legacy SDK

Comment: @AdriánPastoriza sorry to hear that we're confusing you. That's never a good sign. If you stick to the docs on https://firebase.google.com/docs/, you should not run into this problem. But if you do, asking for help is totally fine.