# Android - Firebase Crashlytics - "Failed to retrieve settings"

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have troubles making Firebase crash reporting send logs to firebase (Can't see any crashes in firebase console)

I found that previously I've created project in Fabric Crashlytics and removed it today

As far as I know I have configured my android project properly. So maybe I'm just missing something in firebase console. Code is successfully compiled and `Fabric.isInitialized() == true`

project -> build.gradle

```
   classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
   classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.1'
```

app -> build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

No `<meta-data>` in manifest and no `Fabric.with` in `Application`. So clear configuration. Project itself is however pretty huge.

After invoking crash using `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()` this is output in console using `adb logcat -s Fabric CrashlyticsCore`

```
I CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.8.32
E Fabric  : Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/*******/settings
W CrashlyticsCore: Received null settings, skipping report submission!
```

So main problem is probably I'm not receiving settings and have no idea what that means

Comment: When you build your project did you see in the build log that the file `google-services.json` is taken into account?

Comment: `Parsing json file: /home/***/google-services.json` and no error there

Comment: Look if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192218/failed-to-retrieve-settings-from-https-settings-crashlytics-com-spi-v2-platfor) could be of any help.

Comment: Looks like I only needed to have "Editor" permission on the project. I'm not sure about that, but I didn't change anything else

Answer (score 5):

This is dumb but someone may have the same issue:

I had a proxy running while I was debugging, so the emulator couldn't reach the Firebase servers.

Configuring the proxy/emulator correctly fixed the problem

Comment: Had a vpn ON, I feel bad with myself, thanks bro, it helped me

Comment: Had qustodio on!

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add this in case someone has this issu. I was getting the `Failed to retrieve settings ....` error despite Dashboard working. Turns out you have to enable Crashlytics. I had another app on the same project so it wasn't showing me the enable button until I switched to that app.