# E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Failed to retrieve settings from https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/XXXX/settings

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I tried new Firebase Crashlytics SDk after migrating from Fabric and seem to run into a weird issue.

Crash logs are not captured in dashboard after upgrading `firebase-crashlytics to 17.0.0` and I get this error in log:

E/FirebaseCrashlytics: Failed to retrieve settings from https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/gmp/XXXX/settings

and I followed all instructions from firebase console quickstart guide. Please help me if any one have faced similar issue.

Comment: Please refer to my [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62887994/4374362) for this issue with flavors.

Comment: my case - firebase-settings.crashlytics.com was being blocked by Pi-hole - a raspberry pi based DNS level blocker :(

Comment: ReInstalling the app worked for me

Comment: Same as @AjayGautam, for me pfBlocker was blocking https://firebase-settings.crashlytics.com

Answer (score 34):

In my case, I had migrated the **release** version but I guess I never enabled Crashlytics on the Firebase console for the **debug** variant.

A simple mistake, but putting it here in case it helps out someone else.

Comment: Yup had to click Enable in the FB console. Thanks!

Comment: How do we enable it from console? Could you please give more information about it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Hilal go to Firebase Console > Crashalytics > Click Enable > Wait 5-10min

Comment: This worked for me. must be accepted answer

Comment: Can't believe I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 20):

If you enabled **multiple apps in single project**, ensure you choose the correct one (**left drop down** menu choose the correct project which hold the multiple apps, **right drop down** menu choose the correct running app). I made such mistake and keep looking on the wrong app page and **enabling Crashlytics on the wrong app** and of course I get that error "`Failed to retrieve settings from https://...`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my case, There was a legacy firebase project which using same package name of app. When I deleted legacy firebase project and It's works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Firebaser here -

We often see these kinds of errors after upgrading due to some sort of configuration error when you were switching out your dependencies. Did you make sure to follow all the steps in [this guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=android)?

You may also want to [enable Crashlytics debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?platform=android#enable_debug_logging) and force a test crash to see if the logs give you any other output. And it may help to edit your original question with your Gradle files and any other relevant Crashlytics setup.

Comment: luckly for my case, the issue was fixed after updating to firebase-crashlytics 17.0.1

Comment: @Santhosh my case is the oppose to you: just after update to 17.0.1 I got this error.

Comment: Would you be able to post a full log file? Or reach out to Firebase support with it if you don't want to post it here? Sounds strange. Debug mode would output more info as well, so try enabling that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=ios#enable_debug_logging

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here with 17.2.1, one of my app flavours didnt't work throwing above error. Removing current apps and re-adding them in firebase project settings solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had an issue with the firebase apps and had to re-create the android app on firebase. This meant I had to update the google-services.json file.

After doing this, firebase remote config worked but analytics and crashlytics did not.

Turns out android studio was using-an auto generated file values.xml. This contained

```
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">1:xxxxxxx:android:yyyyyyyy</string>
```

The yyyyyy part of it was still using the old value from the previous google-services.json file. Deleting this file for all flavors, debug and release builds, coupled with an invalidate caches + restart
might do the trick, but just to be safe, what fixed it for me was:

- commenting all the firebase libs from all gradle files
- syncing gradle
- project will not compile at this points since it cant find Firebase dependencies
- invalidate caches + restart
- uncomment firebase libs in all gradle files
- sync gradle
- run app and check if firebase crashlytics works

I am using Android studio 4.1.2

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the google-services.json file, i.e changed it with a one from a different project, you should do the following:

1. Comment out all the crashlytics dependencies in the gradle files
2. Build the app
3. Invalidate cache and restart
4. Uncomment crashlytics dependencies and rebuild app

This should fix the problem if it's caused by cached values from the previous json file for crashlytics.