# Firebase console show this while choose Crashlytics with iOS "We'll be listening for your app to communicate with our servers"

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, crashlytics

Please guide me! Why Firebase console take much time to communicate with server. I'm waiting one and half hour to complete this takes. Anybody tell me what is the reason behind this issue or anyone facing this issue before.

Not show the Graph.

[image: Check this]

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I followed the documentation and used the latest sdk but still not working. I haven't found and answer too. I have just sent a message to Firebase Support on these matter, no response yet.

Comment: @Rhusfer I solved this problem by doing these steps :
-> Uninstall App from simulator or Real Device 
-> Run the app on Simulator or Real device then stop running.
-> And then Open the App that Install on Simulator or Real device.
-> Open Firebase Console project And Refreshed it.

Comment: Just a reminder, ensure you've chosen the correct app in multi-apps project, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65545734/1074998)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, I solved this problem by doing these steps:

1. Make sure you follows the all steps that mentioned in Firebase Documentation Crashlytics.
2. Use fatalError() for crash your app.
3. Uninstall App from simulator or Real Device
4. Run the app on Simulator or Real device then stop running.
5. And then Open the App that Install on Simulator or Real device.
6. Open Firebase Console project And Refresh it.

Comment: I managed to get it work on simulator after deleting the app, then running with `fatal()` line prepared after few seconds later after launch, and the app was running without attaching to the Xcode.

Answer (score 16):

Please make your app force fully crash 2-3 times, after disconnecting your app from Xcode.

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen as a result of several different issues, however they're usually connected to your app being unable to make the proper call to the Crashlytics settings endpoint. You can either write in to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support), or feel free to start a private thread with me, and I can check your apps settings in the Firebase backend.

Comment: Hi Oleg!  I am having the same issue.  Any chance you can take a look on my behalf as well?

Comment: I would need some of your apps info, such as bundle/Project ID, so you can either message me on a private thread, or post it here if you feel comfortable enough doing so.

Comment: I am also having same issue.How did you fixed it ?

Comment: @OlegKodysh,I am also having same issue.Can you check it ?

Comment: I followed each step but I am unable to see the crash report on Crashlytics Dashboard. Can you check it?

Comment: is there a generic way to resolve this @OlegKodysh

Answer (score 1):

if you followed all steps as per latest crashlytics documents!

try forcing a crash directly with button click on initial view instead of just building and running your app

use fatalError() for crash your app