# Firebase crashlytics Cordova 11.1.0 integration issue

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, mobile

I have a firebase project  linked to two mobile apps, one Android and the other IOS, developed using cordova 11.1.0. The integration of firebase services has been done with cordova-plugin-firebase and all features like authentication and realtime db are currently working except for crashlytics. The plugin used is https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-crashlytics?activeTab=readme . The application compiles and works without conflicts, but it is not able to report crashes to crashlytics. In detail, what is logged by the console after a test crash is “Cannot send reports. Settings are unavailable”(see the attachment).
Searching on stackoverflow this solution([Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192218/failed-to-retrieve-settings-from-https-settings-crashlytics-com-spi-v2-platfor))was found, it implies the unlink and link of the application on firebase console. This way is not currently pursuable, due to the possible side effects on a production environment, which could be, based on our research, account and data lost by users.
In the end, is there a way to fix it without affecting the linked apps? Is there a more stable cordova-plugin that is officially suggested by the firebase team to integrate its services in a cordova mobile app?

[image]