# I have got an error and this is my error :Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

Tags: android

**This is my code**

[image]

**app gradle**

[image]

**Project gradle**

[image]

Comment: DO not attach images of Code . Add code in code format with question .

Answer (score 0):

In your `application class`, initialize `FirebaseApp` in `onCreate()` method and remove it from Your `Activity` in order to have Firebase initialize into entire application, not just to one Activity.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
}
```

Also add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at the end of **app gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    ....
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

For more: [Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android/#answer-45978275)

Make sure that you have added `google-services.json` to your app after regidterin to firebase.
Refer:https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp