# FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) error in ionic 4 with angular

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I'm totally new to ionic and angular. I'm getting an issue in my ionic project. I have installed Angular firebase and firebase plugins. 
Error:

```
Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.xxx.xxx Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

Firestore operations are working properly. But the only problem is when i'm trying to get the device fcm token it's throwing the error.
Here is my code

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule , AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy , IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFirestore , AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
import { FcmService } from './services/notification/fcm.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule, 
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseconfig), 
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    IonSlides,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    AngularFirestore,
    FcmService,
    Firebase
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Events } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { FcmService } from './services/notification/fcm.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private fcm: FcmService,
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  private notificationSetup() {
    this.fcm.getToken();
    this.fcm.onNotifications().subscribe(
      (msg) => {
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
          this.alertSerivce.presentToast(msg.aps.alert);
        } else {
          this.alertSerivce.presentToast(msg.body);
        }
      });
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.notificationSetup();
    });
  }

}
```

**fcm.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FcmService {

  constructor(
    private firebase: Firebase,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private platform: Platform,
  ) { }

  async getToken() {
    let token: string;

    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
       await this.firebase.getToken().then((fcmtoken) => {
        token = fcmtoken
        console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', fcmtoken);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error while getting fcm token', err)
      })
    }

    if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
      await this.firebase.getToken().then((fcmtoken) => {
        token = fcmtoken
        console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', fcmtoken);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error while getting fcm token', err)
      })
      await this.firebase.grantPermission();
    }
    this.alert.presentToast(`FCMToken: ${token}`)
    this.saveToken(token);
    return token
  }

  private saveToken(token) {
    if (!token) return;
    this.storage.set(constants.LocalStorageKeys.fcmToken, token)
    return token
  }

  onNotifications() {
    return this.firebase.onNotificationOpen();
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.1.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "^5.0.0",
     ...
  }
```

I'm i missing anything?. I have been stuck in this issue from 2 days. 
I have followed this 
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-push-notifications-working-with-ionic-4-and-firebase-ad87cc92394e

Comment: have u ever referred to this URL? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android

seems to be a duplicate...

Comment: Where did you initialize firebase? How does it know your firebase database url?

Comment: @JayOrdway I have initialised it `NgModule` imports in `app.module.ts`. I have also initialised manually in android project but still the issue occurs

Answer (score 1):

Try changing libraries in package.json to following versions:

```
     "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.8"
     "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8"
     "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.5.0"
     "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.4.1"
     "com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.4"
```

Also, search for this string:

```
      'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

make sure the version is this one.

Please try if it works.