# how to initialize firebase in roboelctric test

Tags: android, firebase, unit-testing, robolectric

im trying to write test with roboelctric, but when i called:

`ActivityScenario<LogInActivity> logInActivity = ActivityScenario.launch(LogInActivity.class);`

i got an error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.`

(in the activity, the firebase is initialize but on the test it isn't)
how do i slove it? :)

test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LogInActivityTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ActivityScenario<LogInActivity> logInActivity = ActivityScenario.launch(LogInActivity.class);

    }

    @Test
    public void some_test() {
        // WHEN
        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.phoneEditText)).perform(click());


}

    }
```

Comment: It sounds like the process gets initialized before Firebase can get to it. Did you try explicitly initialize `FirebaseApp`, as the message says? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android for an example.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer! :) but it didn't work:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: and by the way, i am a big fan of your videos! :)

Comment: You'll want to show what code you added where to get that error. I must admit that adding this code in an activity is usually not great, and it should probably go into a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: oh sorry, i tried to put it in the setUp() method of the test above, and in the activity OnCreate(), but the result was the same.

Comment: and the code in the activity:
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

and in the test:
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext());

Comment: Did you get this resolved?  I am having the same issue

Comment: Same here, like to know the answer