# Jetpack Compose 'Deploy Preview' crashes due to Firebase Performance

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-performance

I would like to use Jetpack Compose's 'Deploy Preview' functionality. After I tried to deploy, my app crashed due to Firebase Performance. I tried a several unsuccessful solutions, so I'm looking for additional advice.

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.myapp.android.legacy.test. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:186)
at com.google.firebase.perf.FirebasePerformance.getInstance(FirebasePerformance.java:132)
at com.google.firebase.perf.FirebasePerformanceInitializer.onAppColdStart(FirebasePerformanceInitializer.java:29)
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.sendAppColdStartUpdate(AppStateMonitor.java:322)
at com.google.firebase.perf.application.AppStateMonitor.onActivityResumed(AppStateMonitor.java:240)
at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityResumed(Application.java:455)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResumed(Activity.java:1291)
at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1819)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1454)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8111)
...
```

Solution 1

I removed FirebasePerformance from Kotlin and Java files. Same error.

Solution 2

In addition to solution 1, I deleted FirebasePerformance from gradle files. Deploying worked! But I still need Firebase Performance.

Solution 3

The Firebase Performance Monitoring Plugin and Library were disabled via [Disable the library at compile time, but do not allow your app to enable it at runtime](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk?platform=android#disable-at-compile_no-enable-at-run) and [Disable the plugin via a Project Property flag](https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/disable-sdk?platform=android#project-property-flag). No effect on the crash.

Solution 4

Downgraded `com.google.gms:google-services` from 4.3.14 to 4.0.0 - compile error: `Cannot invoke method get() on null object`. Downgraded to 4.2.0 - original issue

Solution 5

Manually called `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` in `MyApplication.onCreate()`. The issue remained the same.

Specs

Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 Patch 1; Kotlin version 1.6.10; Android Tools version 7.0.4; Samsung Galaxy S8 running Android 10

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45977847/make-sure-to-call-firebaseapp-initializeappcontext-first-in-android) will help.

Comment: @AlexMamo I gave the top 4 solutions a shot - no luck

Comment: I have same issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @isifzade I went with solution 2 then undid it