# Can not initialise firebase xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.android

I am Trying to create a xamarin android app that sends data to the firebase database that I have created I initialize it using 
but every time I try to start the app it gives me this exception

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.Instance;
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.GetReference("app6-85d57:");
        myRef.SetValue("hello world"); 
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
}
```

> Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process App6.App6. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initilizeApp(Context) first.

how can i solve this? i can't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Please post more code on where you call the FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this)

Comment: Done. I edited the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FirebaseApp not initializing despite FirebaseApp.initializeApp() being called in Application class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39708272/firebaseapp-not-initializing-despite-firebaseapp-initializeapp-being-called-in)

Comment: @HazemGamal try to move `base.OnCreate(bundle);` on top.

Comment: @lowleetak i tried both and they didn't work out for me

Comment: @Yupi i tried that but didn't work also

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a project in Firebase Console
2. Create an Android app and download the google-services.json. **Please make sure that the package name is the same as the package name use in your app.**
   [image]
3. Add google-services.json to root of Android project and set the Build Action to **"GoogleServicesJson"**. You might need to close solution and reopen it again for this build action to appear.
   [image]
4. Initialise FirebaseApp: `Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);`
5. In my case, the first time also will have Not initialise error. After I clean solution and rebuild again, the error is gone. Then, FirebaseApp is able to initialise normally.

Note: My Android Support Library is v25.4.0.2, Xamarin.Firebase.Database is v42.1021.1